# SQL: Selecionar o item que possua mais registros

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query, datatable

Olá, eu tenho a seguinte tabela MYSQL:

[Ver Tabela](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B30B.png)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso pegar o nm_project_phase que possua mais registros com cd_status maior que 0, mas não sei como poderia fazer isso, procurei por aqui e pelo google, mas não consegui achar uma solução para o problema, alguém por favor conseguiria me ajudar?

O script que utilizei inicialmente para gerar está tabela foi a seguinte:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      nm_project_phase, 
      nm_product, 
      cd_status 
    FROM 
      gerobras.project_phase 
      LEFT JOIN gerobras.product ON gerobras.project_phase.id_project_phase = gerobras.product.id_project_phase 
      LEFT JOIN gerobras.product_history ON gerobras.product_history.id_product = gerobras.product.id_product 
    WHERE 
      id_product_history IN (
        SELECT 
          max(id_product_history) 
        FROM 
          gerobras.product_history 
        GROUP BY 
          id_product
      )
  ) AS PRODUCT
```

Answer (score -2):

É necessário que você agrupe os dados e ordene (de forma decrescente), para então utilizar limit 1 e exibir somente o que mais incide no count.

Acredito que este código resolva seu problema.

```
SELECT nm_project_phase, count(cd_status)
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      nm_project_phase, 
      nm_product, 
      cd_status 
    FROM 
      gerobras.project_phase 
      LEFT JOIN gerobras.product ON gerobras.project_phase.id_project_phase = gerobras.product.id_project_phase 
      LEFT JOIN gerobras.product_history ON gerobras.product_history.id_product = gerobras.product.id_product 
    WHERE 
      id_product_history IN (
        SELECT 
          max(id_product_history) 
        FROM 
          gerobras.product_history 
        GROUP BY 
          id_product
      )
  ) AS PRODUCT where cd_status > 0 
group by nm_project_phase 
order by count(cd_status) desc
limit 1
```